# How to create add url button using Jquery / JQM

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, youtube, html5-canvas

I have a multistage form to post add for my mobile website . One of the steps include an input type `text` for you tube URL.

My question is instead of place to copy paste the you tube URL . I want to create a button and add a handler to it that would take me to youtube.com and elect an URL

Can it be possible using JQuery

Here is a [**JS Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Vicky_Anand/2cJgN/)

As you can see in the fiddle. I want to add url from youtube when this button is clicked
**HTML**

```
<div data-role="page" id="page1">
<div role="main nopad " class="ui-content" style="padding-left: 0 !important;padding-right: 0 !important;padding-top: 0 !important; ">
<p>I want this button to take me to Youtube.com and i could add url from there </p>
<div class="ui-btn ui-icon-camera  ">CLick to add URL</div>
<p>View internal page called <a href="#foo1">bar</a>
</p>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: There is a youtube api: https://developers.google.com/youtube/

Comment: bro but this is for embedding youtube video into the app. I just want to add url to the form. In my Desktop version people are just copy pasting the URL of the video . but as in mobile device it would be difficult so I wanted to write a script which could help to get the url from you tube

Comment: you can use the api to search for videos: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/#Search. They have a video browser example too: https://developers.google.com/youtube/code#JavaScript.  Without the api I'm not sure how you would do it. Youtube won't load into an IFRAME.